# Sum of all 3-digit numbers in which the second digit is bigger than n

Tags: python

I'm supposed to write a program where, if you input a single-digit number *n*, it calculates the sum of all 3-digits numbers in which the second digit is bigger than *n*. I have found those numbers, but have no idea how to get their sum. This is what I have so far:

```
n = int(input("n= "))
c = 0
for a in range(100, 1000):
    c = a // 10 % 10
    if c > n:
        print(a)
```

Comment: Where's the sum part? If you can print them you can sum them. `sum += n`

Comment: your range only needs to go to 1000;  since 1000 is not itself a 3-digit number, you want to stop at 999.

Answer (score 1):

To get the sum you should create a new variable and add every good number to it.
For example:

```
n = int(input("n= "))
c = 0
answer = 0
for a in range(100, 1001):
    c = a // 10 % 10
    if c > n:
        answer += a
print(answer)
```